# A serial port receives the data problem in golang on macOS use tarm/serial

Tags: macos, go, serial-port

I successfully write Byte array to port but failed to read from it. function "read"
return "read /dev/tty.usbserial1: interrupted system call" error, I running it on macOS sierra 10.12.6, use "github.com/tarm/serial", anyone met the same problem?
here is the code:

```
func TestTarmSerialDataRecvAndSend(t *testing.T) {
    c := &serial.Config{
        Name: "/dev/cu.usbserial1",
        Baud: 9600,
    }

    s, err := serial.OpenPort(c)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        n, err := s.Write([]byte("test"))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        fmt.Printf("send byte : %v", n)
    }

    fmt.Println("send over")

    buf := make([]byte, 128)
    n, err := s.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("%q", buf[:n])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func sendCommand(p *serial.Port, command string, waitForOk bool) string {
    log.Println("--- SendCommand: ", command)
    var status string = ""
    p.Flush()
    _, err := p.Write([]byte(command))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    buf := make([]byte, 32)
    var loop int = 1
    if waitForOk {
        loop = 10
    }
    for i := 0; i < loop; i++ {
        // ignoring error as EOF raises error on Linux
        n, _ := p.Read(buf)
        if n > 0 {
            status = string(buf[:n])
            log.Printf("SendCommand: rcvd %d bytes: %s\n", n, status)
            if strings.HasSuffix(status, "OK\r\n") || strings.HasSuffix(status, "ERROR\r\n") {
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return status
}
```

the solutions is here: https://golang.hotexamples.com/examples/github.com.tarm.serial/Port/Read/golang-port-read-method-examples.html